# Spring web service request format int with leading zero

Tags: java, spring, string, integer, wsdl

I am using Spring web services to connect to a secure url and send a SOAP request. A particular field is defined in the wsdl as:
<xs:element minOccurs="1" name="collectionDay" type="xs:int"/>

I use genjaxb to generate classes from the wsdl, so this field is generated as:

...

`*         &lt;element name="collectionDay" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int"/&gt;`

...

`protected int collectionDay;`

...

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the collectionDay property.
 * 
 */
public int getCollectionDay() {
    return collectionDay;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the collectionDay property.
 * 
 */
public void setCollectionDay(int value) {
    this.collectionDay = value;
}
```

...

The problem is that the host is expecting any single digit days (1st through 9th) to be sent as:
"&ltcollectionDay&gt03&lt/collectionDay&gt" (with a leading 0)

It is easy if I can convert it to String, but Spring generates the request somewhere in the unknown, based on the generated classes, so this field is expecting int, but generates the field as:

"&ltcollectionDay&gt3&lt/collectionDay&gt"
(without the leading zero)

The only option I see at this point is to save the WSDL locally and manually change the field type to string, so that the java classes are generated with the modified field type. The url is hosted at a bank, so no chance of them making any changes.

Comment: Yeah, there is no way to add that leading zero by keeping it an int. As you said, you have to use string there. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

This is answered here: [Can I zero-pad an integer in an XSD-generated class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856324/can-i-zero-pad-an-integer-in-an-xsd-generated-class)

Getting an end-system to fix their stuff is a pain and often not an option.